# jQuery tag selections different response on different sites

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have recently been stumped by a console log by jQuery 3.2.1

The code basically uses this

```
$("[href=#][target]")
```

From an internal domain this works as intended, but from another server internal, but is public this causes a console log error of

```
Unrecognised expression
```

The obvious is

```
$("[href='#'][target]")
```

And this then works in both, but my question is why is this only causing errors in one site but not another,

All the files are loaded locally to the site, and the one it fails on is the fastest of the group.